# My Vue3 project's Google Classroom API Javascript compiled incorrectly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-api, vuejs3, google-classroom

I am trying to retrieve the list of classrooms I handle, and I tried implementing this code that I retrieved from [Google Classroom Javascript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/js?fbclid=IwAR2Qq2ApihVwcMEHermoLpQU7XTGld-tL9ZReSnCwpff6EnEIbFwo6NhJfY#python-3.x) and implemented it on my Vue3 project.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

const CLIENT_ID = '<MY_CLIENT_ID>;
const API_KEY = '<MY_API_KEY>';

// Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://classroom.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest';

// Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
// included, separated by spaces.
const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly';

let tokenClient;
let gapiInited = false;
let gisInited = false;
let gapi = window.gapi;

export default{
   data(){
        return {
            error: "",
            courses: "",
        };
   },
   methods: {
    gapiLoaded(){
            axios.get("https://apis.google.com/js/api.js").then(()=>{
                gapi.load('client', intializeGapiClient);
            })
        },
        
        async initiazlieGapiClient(){
            await gapi.client.init({
                apiKey: API_KEY,
                discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
            });
            gapiInited = true;
            maybeEnableButtons();
        },

        gisLoaded(){
            axios.get("https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client").then(() => {
                tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
                client_id: CLIENT_ID,
                scope: SCOPES,
                callback: '',
            });
                gisInited = true;
                maybeEnabledButtons();
            })
        },

        maybeEnableButtons() {
            if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        },

        handleAuthClick(){
            tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
                if(resp.error !== undefined) {
                    throw(resp);
                }
                document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
            };
            if(gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
                tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
            } else {
                tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
            }
        },
        
        handleSignoutClick(){
            const token = gapi.client.getToken();
            if(token !== null){
                google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
                gapi.client.setToken('');
                document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
                document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
        },

        async listCourses() {
            let response;
            try {
            response = await gapi.client.classroom.courses.list({
                pageSize: 10,
            });
            } catch (err) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
            return;
            }

            const courses = response.result.courses;
            if (!courses || courses.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No courses found.';
            return;
            }
            // Flatten to string to display
            const output = courses.reduce(
                (str, course) => `${str}${course.name}\n`,
                'Courses:\n');
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = output;
        },

        mounted: function(){
            this.gapiLoaded();
            this.gisLoaded();
        },
  },
}
</script>
```

I'm having 5 errors, saying that it
`Compiled with problems: ERROR [eslint]`
`'initializedGapiClient' is not defined no-undef`
`'maybeEnableButtons' is not defined no-undef`
`'google' is not defined no-undef`
`'maybeEnableButtons' is not defined no-undef`
`'google' is not defined no-undef`
`5 problems (5 errors, 0 warnings)`
What could be the solution to my problem here? Did I implemented it wrong? Thank you for anyone that will help me!

Comment: I do not know how the google classrooms API works but a few of these are from typo errors and not using the `this` keyword.  you've typo'd the function name "initiazlieGapiClient".  you need to call maybeEnableButtons as `this.maybeEnableButtons()`

Comment: Where should I call ```this.maybeEnableButtons()```? Should I call them inside mounted?

Comment: Edit: I called ```this.maybeEnableButtons()``` in ```gisLoaded``` and ```initializeGapiClient``` functions and the error ```maybeEnableButtons``` and ```initializeGapiClient``` is now gone. All was left was ```'google' is not defined no-undef```. What could be the problem here?